# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I try to start video but I get an Error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("video")[0].play()')
```

But everything works perfectly in another browsers

```
$('a').bind('click', function() {
  $('video')[0].play();
});

<video controls>
  <source id="webm" src="/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source id="mp4" src="/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Comment: wrap your code inside `document.ready` handler

Comment: Ok where is a.js-video-popup-button-new

Comment: @Pilot ofcourse it's wrapped

Comment: what is `console.log($('video').length)`

Comment: @Tamizh it's just an <a> tag

Comment: @iJay come on whats this?

Comment: @Pilot "number" in any browser

Comment: @Anton2012 what number?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48262/discussion-between-pilot-and-anton2012)

Comment: It seems your plugin which has `play()` function is not loaded properly.

Comment: @Mr_Green it's not a plugin it's html5 method http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: @Pilot I'm right there

Comment: [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CSTPv/50/)

Comment: @Anton2012 check demo.and join chat instead of commenting here

Comment: @Anton2012 what is `console.log($('video').length)?????`

Comment: @Pilot yeah man I've been checking it and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why this hasn't been correctly answered by now, but here goes:

The latest Safari version for Windows is very old (v5 was originally released in 2010) and most likely doesn't support html5 video, and thus the DOM element looked up by `$('video')[0]` has no `play()` function.

Comment: Source?

`Safari supports the <video> and <audio> media elements on iOS 3.0 and later and in Safari 3.1 and later on the desktop (Mac OS X and Windows).` 

[Developer Apple: Video introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html)
 // 
[Developer Apple: Controlling media with JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Okay, this little 'test' proved it to me: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: @Smamatti maybe I was a bit quick to answer this one, and my answer was actually more of a qualified guess. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) agrees that there has been "basic support" in Safari since 3.1, but [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) says support was added in 7.1. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

If you use safari on windows, you must install **QuickTime** player. Without it video will not play.

Answer (score 0):

`play` is not a jQuery function but a function of the DOM element. You therefore need to call it upon the DOM element.

You can try this:

```
 $('video').get(0).play();
```

if you wanted to do this to fit in with an existing jQuery selection -- would be `$('#videoId').get(0).play()`.

---

Updates:

I think you have to use `.preventDefault()` method too. so as per your code you can try with adding the event to `preventDefault()`.

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('video')[0].play();
});
```

Comment: The same Error
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("video").get(0).play()')

Comment: What is the version of your safari browser.

Comment: The last version for Windows

Comment: @Jai `$("video")[0]` will return you the DOM element not the jQuery object as the play method is not the jquery method its the DOM method

Comment: He is calling it on the DOM element already. And not calling `preventDefault()` would not explain the error he is getting.